# Time Picker Wheel advanced :: Android

Tags: android

I have third party library which generates wheel between given number range. but i also want to put "AM" "PM" in a separate wheel too. how can i do it. any suggestion?

I want this patron or time picking -> http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/date-and-time-picker-wheel

Comment: I have a car and want to tune the engine. How can I do it? Any suggestion? => To few information. What library? Open Source/Closed Source?

Comment: yes @schlingel is correct please specify full information

Comment: Sorry for that. actually i want to ask that i want to make a time picker wheel. I have successfully done "Hours" and "Min" wheel animation. but i want a wheel for "AM" and "PM" too. this library only gives number picker.
Library Link-> https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker

Comment: Look at this example i want to do the same thing
[link](http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/date-and-time-picker-wheel)